# test check user logged in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I have a simple route to function:

```php
if (Auth::check()) {
    return response()->json('true');
} else {
    return response()->json('false');
}
```

I need to test this function, with something like this from PHPUnit:

```php
$this->get('auth/checkLoggedIn')
     ->seeJson([true]);
```

How do I simulate that the test user is logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return the response something like this:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    return response()->json(["logged"=>true]);
} else {
    return response()->json(["logged"=>false]);
}
```

Using laravel's factory model, create a sample user. To avoid the TokenMismatch error, you can use the WithoutMiddleware trait. But if its a `GET` request, you don't need that. But if it's a `POST` then you probably need that.

So you can use either

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;

UserTest extends TestCase {

use WithoutMiddleware;

/**
*@test
*/
public function it_tests_authentication()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $this->actingAs($user);

    $this->post('auth/checkLoggedIn')
             ->seeJson(["logged"=>true]);

//or GET depending on your route

        $this->get('auth/checkLoggedIn')
         ->seeJson(["logged"=>true]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `actngAs($user_id)` to simulate a logged in user.

A fuller example:

```
  // simulate ajax request
        $this->actingAs($user_id)               
            ->post(route('api.bookmark.store'), [
                'event' => $this->event->id,
                '_token' => csrf_token()
            ]);
```